# Tracking scientific error when working with floating-point numbers

Tags: .net, math

**Background**

I hate the way .Net/IEEE-754 handles equality of floating-point numbers (FPNs) (i.e. double, float). It requires the programmer to be prescient with respect to the yet-to-be-determined history of the number, as the programmer must choose a 'reasonable' value of epsilon where frequently no such value can be determined (as the programmer cannot determine ahead of time how many operations, hence roundings, the number will be subject to).

I would like to create a 'better' FPN within .Net. At creation, one would set its initial scientific error (or accept a default; the default being the minimum). When one performed operations on the FPN, those operations would update the scientific error (to account for the effect of rounding). When testing the equality of two FPNs, one could determine if their ranges overlapped (and even the probability that they are the same number).

**Question**

The code itself is simple, my questions are:

- How do operations (+ - * / to start with) affect the scientific error of a FPN? Are there formulae for determining this scientific error?
- I understand that an added complication is the uneven distribution of FPNs. This can obviously be accounted for by scaling the error in proportion to the inherent scientific error of the result; but is there a formula for determining the inherent scientific error present in a given FPN?

Comment: You are aware this isn't ".NET's floating point numbers" - it's "IEEE-754 floating point numbers" right?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I am, but I only hate the way .Net handles them because I'm not working with other languages presently ;-) I flip/flopped between writing ".Net" and "most programming language" a few times.

Comment: You do not mean “scientific error”. That term is not used in numerical computing. Perhaps you are thinking of something like scientific notation, which scales, so you actually mean relative error.

Comment: As one answer has mentioned, interval arithmetic may provide some of what you seek, but it cannot provide the probability that two results are the same number (that is, that they are the results of computations that would produce the same number of performed with exact arithmetic) for several reasons. First, you would need probability distributions of the input values. Second, tracking the probability distributions would be much harder than tracking simple intervals. Third, if the probability distributions are continuous, the probability that two numbers are equal is usually zero.

Comment: Why do you say the programmer cannot determine ahead of time how many operations a number will be subjected to? Much numerical code uses a number of operations that is determined at the time the code is written.

Comment: What work are you trying to do with floating-point arithmetic? Floating-point arithmetic has been a huge success, and many people have found various ways to deal with the rounding that it uses. However, these ways are dependent on their applications. Interval arithmetic might seem to have some allure, but it has not been nearly as popular as basic floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: It is not true that relative error always grows. A trivial example is a constant function, f(*x*) = 1. Regardless of the relative error of the input, the output has zero relative error. Of course, there are also non-trivial functions which reduce relative error: Any function such that |f'(*x*)| < |f(*x*)/x|, such as log(*x*) for e < *x*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A simple example of where a programmer cannot know how many operations a FPN will be subject to is solving a system of linear equations. With an optimised algorithm, the number of operations will depend on the values (which can only be determined at runtime).

Comment: And no, I do mean "scientific error", although in science we just call it "error" (which I felt would be too ambiguous). Scientific error is the "difference between a computed, estimated, or measured value and the accepted true, specified, or theoretically correct value" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error#Science_and_engineering

Comment: How big a system of linear equations do you expect to have to solve? I've only dealt with up to a few thousand equations. At that sort of size, with 64 bit binary floats, floating point rounding error is very manageable. "Scientific error" is a very broad category - it would include instrument errors in measuring the physical quantities on which the program operates. "Rounding error" is a more precise term for the type of error you seem to be talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has already been done, see [Interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). This type of automatic floating-point error analysis gives you a reliable upper bound on the accumulated rounding error. Perhaps the biggest disadvantage is the [Dependency problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Dependency_problem) which can lead to correct but way too conservative error bounds.

Comment: Of course, the interval arithmetic version of `==` usually returns only the interval [0, 0] or [0, 1]. It cannot return [1, 1] unless the two inputs are each a single point. Interval arithmetic could state whether two intervals overlap or not, but we do not know whether that will solve the questioner’s underlying problem since they have not described their actual application.

Comment: @Ali Thank you, this is simple and makes sense. It addresses the first of my questions (regarding how to calculate the error present after various basic operations), and has the added benefit of catering for asymmetrical error. Any thoughts on how to deal with the uneven distribution of FPNs (i.e. larger-magnitude numbers inherently having more error than smaller-magnitude numbers)?

Comment: @Mark Interval arithmetic will automagically take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading Hamming's classic book [Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486652416).  He goes into a great deal of detail on the nature of floating-point numbers and of numbers in science in general.  (Interesting tidbit: Floating point numbers are not uniformly distributed, and neither are the fundamental constants of physics, but the the two distributions are similar.)

In any computational problem, you have to have some idea what constitutes a "good" answer.  In simplest form: what value of epsilon is appropriate?  For example, for problems with distances measured in astronomical units (1 AU = 93 million miles, approximately), epsilon of 1 mile corresponds to 1E-8 relative error.  Depending on what you are doing, that may or may not be enough.